# Finding websites IP through reading lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to achieve a task that a script can load a file and iterate through lines and finding domain ip from each line.

Tried doing it with this code:

```
import socket

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        i.strip('\n')
        i.strip('\t')
        i.strip('\r')
        print(socket.gethostbyname(i))

f.close()
```

But shows error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ip.py", line 8, in 
>       print(socket.gethostbyname(i)) socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The string you found could not be resolved as a hostname. You will have to catch the exception.

Comment: Even tried that too but result was same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `string.strip` doesn't modify the string, rather, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed.

Therefore, you can do something like the following:

```
import socket

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        i = i.strip('\n')
        i = i.strip('\t')
        i = i.strip('\r')
        print(socket.gethostbyname(i))

f.close()
```

Running that on a `test.txt` that looks like:

```
test.com
google.com
yahoo.com
```

I get:

```
69.172.200.235
172.217.26.110
98.138.219.232
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below. it worked.
Issue is like you might be having other strings too apart from host name which might be throwing exception.

```
import socket

a = ['word2','www.google.co.in','word3']
for i in a:
    try:
        i.strip('\n')
        i.strip('\t')
        i.strip('\r')
        print(socket.gethostbyname(i))
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Unable to get Hostname and IP")
```

Output:

```
Unable to get Hostname and IP
172.217.195.94
Unable to get Hostname and IP
```

Comment: i guess i tried remove new lines but it isn't working.
My test.txt is as follows.
test.com
google.com
yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

I wasn't saving the split result in my i variable which was not removing the new line character after each domain..
Appreciate every comments.

Thanks